# How to use jest mockImplemention for default export module?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, mocking, jestjs

Packages:

- "react": "16.2.0"
- "jest": "22.0.4"

Because I would need different mock implementation depending of the test, I am trying to get the equivalent of

```
import Component from '../component.js'
jest.mock('../component.js', () => {
  return () => <div>Component</div>
});
```

which if working but this time using mockImplementation.

Going through stackoverflow made me try those following implementation without success:

```
jest.mock('../component.js')
Component.mockImplementation(() => {
  return {
    render: () => <div>MockComponent</div>
  };
});
```

or

```
jest.mock('../component.js', () => jest.fn())
Component.mockImplementation(() => {
  return () => <div>Component</div>
});
```

or

```
jest.mock('../component.js')
Component.mockImplementation(() => {
  return () => <div>Component</div>
});
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I would say that you have to return just a function instead of returning a function that returns a function. I think something like this should do the trick:

```
jest.mock('../component.js')
Component.mockImplementation(() => <div>Component</div>);
```